# OOP and Inheritance in Flash

Tags: oop, flash, inheritance

Good day,

I have a MovieClip in the Library called "Pic".

Then I drag 4 instances of "Pic" from Library to the stage, and set their instance names "p1" to "p4".

I have coded a superclass called "Pic.as" and 4 subclasses "P1.as" to "P4.as", that each of them extends "Pic.as"

Now the question is how should I Link those 4 subclasses to those 4 instances of "Pic" on the stage - P1 to P4 - when there is only 1 MovieClip in the Library that is "Pic"?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

If you share your code's we can understand what you need and help for it.

If you want to learn about OOP programing you can look here:http://tv.adobe.com/watch/actionscript-11-with-doug-winnie/objectoriented-programming-episode-45/

Hope this one help ;)